# Necessary and sufficient condition that a norm is differentiable

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

I've seen this property in my book over differential functions:

Let $x\in E=\mathbb{R}^n$ with norm $N$. $E^*$ is the dual space of $E$ (linear functions from $E$ to $\mathbb{R}$) with triple norm $N^*(\phi)=\sup_{x\not=0}{\dfrac{|\phi(x)|} {N(x)}}$.

Define $J(x)=\{\phi\in E^*:N^*(\phi)\le1,\phi(x)=N(x)\}$.

The property says that:

$N$ is differentiable at $x\in E$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $J(x) $ has only 1 function.

I'm stuck at the direction from right to left. Suppose $x\in E$, $J(x)=\{\phi\}$. With the help of the hint in the book, I've shown that if $(x_n)$ converges to $x$, then if we take a $\phi_n$ in $J(x_n)$, $(\phi_n)$ converges to $\phi$ (they are all in a compact ball). Here I'm confused :

1. The book says we could find a contradiction here if it's not differentiable at $x$. I tried to construct a sequence converging to $x$ but I can't control the difference between $\phi_n(x)$ with $\phi(x)$ to be at the level of $N(x_n-x)$ even it is convergent.
2. I can't prove why we could "take" a $\phi_n$ in $J(x_n)$, as I can't show that there exists a neighborhood of $x$ where each element is associated with a non empty $J$...

Would someone like to give a hint?~